# Sum of $n$ random selected elements

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

Let's you have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
\mathbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & \mathbf{6} & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & \mathbf{12} \\
13 & 14 & \mathbf{15} & 16 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

If you select four entries $a_{ij}$ located on different rows and columns, the sum will always be $34$.

For example, $1 + 6 + 12 + 15 = 34$.

**Question.** Is it possble to find the sum for the $n \times n$ random  matrix with ordered elements before selection $n$ elements?

**Edit 1.** The element $a_{11}$ can be great that $1$.
**Edit 2.** The elements $a_{ij}$ can be an arithmetic progression.

Comment: $$\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2n}$$

Comment: What could be simpler than $\sum_{k=0}^n(kn+k+1)$?

Comment: @Did, thank for the answer. But I have tried to add the remark into the question.